# Biblatex: subdivided categories

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

I'm trying to create a complex subdivided bibliography for my Master thesis using:

```
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{primary}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{secondary}
\addtocategory{primary}{primaire}
\addtocategory{secondary}{secondaire}
```

in the preambule as I sorted my sources by the keywords "primaire" and "secondaire".
This, by using the commands:

```
\printbibliography{category=primary, heading=subbibliography,%
            title={Sources Primaires}}
\printbibliography{category=secondary,heading=subbibliography,%
            title={Sources Secondaires}}
```

enabled me to have two subdivisions in the bibliography entitled "Sources primaires" and "Sources secondaires".

My issue is that I have different types of primary sources and different types of secondary sources that I want to subdivide by using several keywords in the bib file. In the primaray category I want to sort them by type and in the secondary by keywords, having eventually a bibliography with two big category, each one being subdivided in several sub-categories (each sub-category having it's own heading title).

I've looked through the biblatex documentation without finding an answer. I now how to separate both (creating categories or having a subdivided bibliography by type or keywords) but I don't see anything about "subdividing categories" 
themselves.

I hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: Would it be an option for you to create only the subcategories (e.g. using primary + article as keywords for those), and make a chapter called "Sources primaires", then add all pertinent sub-bibliographies (telling BiblaTeX to print them as sections). Then create the second chapter the same way.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why don't you simply combine the filters? e.g. `\printbibliography[category=.., keyword=..., type=...]`

Comment: @ienissei Yes you are right that could be a solution! I'm a beginner with biblatex and I shall admit that I was just looking at the section "subdivided bibliography" in the biblatex documentation and I did not realize I could include them in different chapters... When say that do you mean actual chapters in my document or biblatex is able to create specific chapters in a bibliography?

Comment: By default, `biblatex` creates a chapter with no number called "Bibliography". Just use `\chapter*{Sources primaires}` for a similar result, and then tell `biblatex` to print your different bibliographies as sections (that's somewhere in the manual), so they get under your chapter heading and look like section headings. Does that answer your question? `Biblatex` can also write bibliographies per chapter of your document, but I think that wasn't your question.